# Rspec: model not updated when submitting form with js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a **paper** model. Which has two states: **draft** and **approved**.

I have a form on edit_paper_path which makes a **put** with **remote: true**.

My controller:

```
def update
  paper = Paper.find(params[:id])
  puts paper.status # => :draft
  paper.approved!
  puts paper.status # => :approved
end
```

My test is:

```
it 'changes status to Approved', js: true do
  expect {
    click_button 'Approve'
  }.to change { paper.status }
end
```

But the test fails, and I noticed that the change done in the controller on the model, is lost, so **the status keeps being :draft**.

Additional:

This is my database_cleaner config:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.append_after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara AJAX requests run asynchronously, so `paper.status` is being evaluated before the value is updated in the database.

In fact, Capybara is decoupled from the database, so you should try to test your ajax update by querying the DOM itself using the typical `has_content`/`has_css` query methods Capybara provides.

You could fix this by using `sleep` to wait for the transaction to finish, but that's a bit of a hacky solution and isn't guaranteed to pass depending on how long it takes for the database commit to take place.

Another option is wait until the AJAX call completes by using a `jQuery.active` query script. There's a good article that explains this approach here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara.

Answer (score 2):

Your test is failing since the controller updates the record in the database while your test is operating on the model held in memory.

What you need to do is sync the representation in memory with the DB:

```
it 'changes status to Approved' do
  expect(paper.approved?).to be_falsy # sanity check
  click_button 'Approve'
  # trick to get capybara to wait for request to finish 
  # note that there actually needs to be a flash message
  expect(page).to have_css(".flash") 
  paper.reload
  expect(paper.approved?).to be_truthy
end
```

Edited with feedback from Anthony E to deal with race conditions.

Comment: This might work, but isn't guaranteed as it introduces a race condition. If the model reloads before the update commits to the DB, the old value will still be retrieved.

Comment: True @AnthonyE - I would not really use this if the test was asyncronous - better to leave feature specs for actually testing the user story and use a request or controller spec to test the direct effects.

Comment: Right, but feature tests with Capybara are asynchronous, even without an AJAX call, as in your example. However, using `has_content/has_css` with Capybara > 2.0 will block until the page content is found, or a timeout occurs.